# Count <li> in all <ul> and count all specific <a> in one line code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I wrote a Python code to analyze a web page through Beautiful Soup.

Once the code was finished, I started removing unnecessary variables and lines.

I'm also trying to remove for loops, if possibile.

For example, I'd like to replace these two loops (which are in two different files) with a one line code (eg `len(an object)`):

### (1) Count `<li>` in all `<ul>`

```
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
list = soup.find_all('ul',{'class':'class-name'})
counter = 0
for ul in list:
    for li in ul:
        counter += 1
```

where the `list` object is something like this

```
[<ul class="class-name">
<li class="section"><a href="...">...</a></li>
<li class="section"><a href="...">...</a></li>
<li class="section"><a href="...">...</a></li></ul>, 
<ul class="class-name">
<li class="section"><a href="...">...</a></li>
<li class="section"><a href="...">...</a></li></ul>]
```

### (2) Count all specific `<a>`

```
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
list = soup.find('table',{'class':'class-name'}).find_all('a')
counter = 0
for el in list:
    if el.contents[0] != 'Train':
        counter += 1
```

where `list` is something like

```
[<a href="…">Train</a>,
<a href="…">Car</a>,
<a href="…">Plane</a>]
```

### What I tried

Using `numpy`, but the commands `np.array(list)` and `np.asarray(list)` get an error in both cases:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    np.array(list)
  File "C:\...\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1016, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 0
```

In case (2) I tried using the slice notation to retrieve element by element, but commands such as `list[1:3]` return another  array. So for example this code, which is an attempt to get the `total length minus the number of elements whose contents[0] is 'Train'`, doesn't work:

```
counter = len(list) - (list[:].contents[0] == 'Train')
```

Is it possibile to replace the two loops with a one line code?

Comment: Not sure what exactly your aiming for, but look into Python's map, filter and reduce functions. [This](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~erdmann/mse350/topics/list_comprehensions.html) and [this](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) looks like nice tutorials.

Comment: For example, the last example you gave could be `counter = count(filter(lambda x: x.contents[0] != 'Train', list)`.

Comment: Thank you but the answer solve the problem easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first loop :

```
counter = sum(1 for ul in list for li in ul)
```

For the second one :

```
counter = sum(1 for el in list if el.contents[0] != 'Train')
```

Comment: This is amazing thank you very much! I'm reading the Python documentation about "sum iterable" to understand what that "1" is about, but it seems an hidden fact because I don't find about it. What is it? Thanks again

Comment: Doing some testing, it seems that the `sum(x for ...)` command, where x is a number, performs the for loop and multiply the result by x

Comment: It just serves to create a list of 1. Then summing the ones will give you the value you want. For example, `[1 for i in range(5)]` will create this list `[1,1,1,1,1]`. `sum([1,1,1,1,1])` gives you 5. But you can directly write `sum(1 for i in range(5))`

Answer (score 1):

[strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) in-built function of Python is used to remove all the leading and trailing spaces from a string.
[sum()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sum)-in-built function takes an iterable and returns the sum of items in it

```
list1 = soup.find('table',{'class':'class-name'}).find_all('a')
counter = len(list1) - sum(1 for a in list1 if a.text.strip() == 'Train')
```

Comment: Thank you, Corentin answer is complete so I chose it